# WSO2 APIM live log viewer through a proxy

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Anybody in stackoverflow land have the live log viewer working through a proxy? This is what mine looks like...

[image: LLV through proxy]

If I go directly to port 9443, everything works. Any help would be appreciated.